# Install Windows Server 2008 Core on a Dell Optiplex 790

Tags: virtualization, dell, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

Does anybody have experience installing Windows Server 2008 Core on a Dell Optiplex 790? When I connect to the machine with the Hyper-V Manager Administrator snap-in, and try to create and run a virtual machine, I get the error "The Virtual Machine could not be started because the hypervisor is not running". I've disabled the Execute Disable functionality in the BIOS as was requried for other Dell models, but no matter what combination of security and virtualization settings I use on the machine, I can't get this working.

EDIT: I've installed Windows Server 2008 Core on a Dell Optiplex 790, and I'm trying to install and setup a guest VM on the Hypervisor

EDIT 2: The Hyper-V role is installed and configured, without any errors in the event log. Hardware-assisted virtualization is also enabled.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?  I'm not understanding where Hyper-V is coming into play... are you trying to install a 2008 core VM guest on a workstation that has Hyper-V installed?

Comment: So are you saying you've installed Windows Server 2008 core and then configured the HyperV role? Were there any errors reported during the configuration of that role? Anything in the event log?

Comment: Do you have hardware assisted virtualization turned on?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on HP machine with VMware. 
First try to uninstall Hyper-V, then enable Virtualization and Data Execution Prevention in the BIOS and after that install Hyper-V again.

Aditional information:
Here I have found some article, with almost the same solution:
http://reidablog.blogspot.com/2008/06/with-correct-bios-settings-enabled-on.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/52811/intel-q65-express-chipset.html says

Intel® Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O (VT-d): No

Intel vPro® Platform Eligibility: No

So even though the CPU supports and the BIOS has options to "turn it on" I'm guessing it doesn't really support it.

Tried updating BIOS to A22.

Checking BIOS "Virtualization-> enabled trusted" results in a boot time message of "Alert! Invalid Trusted Execution Technology" message.